# How can I use DSA without hashing? Openssl + C

Tags: c, openssl

Im wondering if I can use DSA without hashing ... I wrote this code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/dsa.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int bits = 1024;
    unsigned char *buff = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 102409209);
    unsigned int digestLength = 0, signSize = 0;
    digestLength = strlen(buff);

    DSA *dsaKey = NULL;

    if((dsaKey = DSA_generate_parameters(bits, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(DSA_generate_key(dsaKey) != 1)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }

    unsigned char* sign = (unsigned char*)calloc(DSA_size(dsaKey), sizeof(unsigned char));

    int ret = DSA_sign(0, buff, digestLength, sign, &signSize, dsaKey);
    if(ret != 1)
    {
        printf("DSA sign error!\n");
    }

    int is_valid = DSA_verify(0, buff, digestLength, sign, signSize, dsaKey);
    if(is_valid != 1)
    {
        printf("DSA verify error!\n");
    }

    if(dsaKey != NULL)
        DSA_free(dsaKey);
    free(buff);
    free(sign);

    return 0;
}
```

But I dont even know how to check if its correct or not. With hashing its simple - first I compute the hash, and then sign/verify it. But without hashing?

Comment: Without hashing the data, it´s not DSA anymore.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps security.stackexchange.com or crypto.stackexchange.com. Come back when you have a programming question.